# Mongo Ruby Driver #find() on Specified field Values

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query

- Ruby: `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]`
- RubyGem: `mongo (2.0.4)`

I need help querying a MongoDB database with their gem and updating the appropriate fields.

**EDIT:** I'm trying to loop over documents of a Mongo database, pull down the values of specific fields in those documents, and update them later in the script.

Objectives

1. Query the database for documents where the field `partner_id` is "partner" and where the field `state` is "provisioned", and return only the values under the `_id` and `config` fields.

   - After this point, I'll be iterating over each document, generating a password, and updating another database.
2. Update the database with the newly generated password to each documents `config` field.

I'm at my wit's end as I've seen about half a dozen different way to write the syntax, and the documentation is little help unless I already knew how to do these things. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'mongo'

# Fetch the addons database URI and connect.
db_uri = ENV['DATABASE_URI']
client = Mongo::Client.new(db_uri)

# Connect to the needed collection and pull down each document to be looped over individually.
# **Having trouble getting this to work. The result is just '= []' - don't know what I'm doing wrong.
client[:collection].find("partner_id" => "partner", "state" => "provisioned", :fields => ["_id", "config"]).each {

  # Need something here to pull down the values from each document's '_id' and 'config' fields and assign them to variables.
  user_id =
  user_config =
  user_config = JSON.parse(user_config)

  # ...generating password and updating other database...

  # Convert the Hash of the user's new configuration into JSON, and update the original database with it.
  # Not sure if any of this is correct. When querying to check, the database doesn't seem to be updated.
  user_config = user_config.to_json
  client[:collection].update(
    {"_id" => user_id},
    {'$set' => {
      "config" => user_config
      }
    }
  )
}
end
return
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it is late here, but ... _"Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!"_ Any assistance for what ? What is *exactly* the question ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to loop over documents of a Mongo database, pull down the values of specific fields in those documents, and update them later in the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not finding anything because this:

```
:fields => ["_id", "config"]
```

argument to `find` isn't specifying the fields you want, `find` just sees that as a third document field to look for. Your documents probably don't have a field called `field` whose value is an array of those strings so the query silently finds nothing at all.

If you want to limit your query, you need to use [`projection`](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-driver-tutorial/#query-options):

```
client[:collection].find("partner_id" => "partner", "state" => "provisioned")
                   .projection('_id' => 1, 'config' => 1)
                   .each { |doc| ... }
```

Then inside the `each` block the `doc` will be a Hash so you can say:

```
user_id     = doc['user_id']
user_config = doc['user_config']
```

If I'm reading your code right, the `user_config` should be a Hash already so you probably won't need to parse it yourself.

Comment: Awesome! It worked! I've been beating my head against this script for a week and a half, and this was the final piece.

Thank you!